# Put function into a new module which contains objects from the main module? Python

Tags: python

Is ther a way to put function into a new module, which calls functions/objects from the main module?

### Main.py

```
from xxx import some
from yyy import hello
from funtions import function_y

object = some.thing()

def function_x():
    dostuff...
    hello(x, y)

function_y()
```

### functions.py

```
def function_y():
    dostuff...
    object.bye() #object from Main.py
    dostuff...
    function_x() #function from Main.py
```

If I do this like that. I get:

```
NameError: name 'object' is not defined
```

But if i try to import Main.py into the functions.py.. its goin worse..
Yes.. as you can see.. i am a newb.. :-) sorry for that. I just want to structure my code into pieces. for every 
topic another *.py ... but maybe i am wrong? and have to put every code that calls something from the main namespace into the Main.py? Unless i can pass the objects as parameters?

Comment: Can you pass the `object` from main.py to `function_y` as a parameter?

Comment: Yea i think i can do that.. but what to do with `function_x()` inside of `function_y()`? How do i 'import' that?

Comment: Could `function_x()` be moved to functions.py?

Comment: no it will be used everywhere

Comment: That is fine, as long as everywhere can `import functions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the way you want if you import `Main.py` from within `function_y()`:

#### functions.py

```
def function_y():
    import main
    dostuff...
    main.object.bye() #object from Main.py
    dostuff...
    main.function_x() #function from Main.py
```

Comment: Oh yes... this is what i wanted. it works. i had to do it like that `from Main import oject, function_x` ... Thanks :-)

Comment: Even though my answer shows how to do things the way you want, consider re-structuring your modules the way @LukeSmith suggests in his comments. Just because you can do it the way you wanted it originally to work - it does not mean that you should.

Comment: Yea i think its cleaner to do it like they said. but for now i now something more: Its because of the namespace of the function right?

Comment: Yes, you can avoid circular imports by hiding `import main` inside `function_y()` namespace. This allows importing `functions.py` into `main.py` without conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest following structure.

**functions.py**

```
from yyy import hello

def function_x():
    dostuff...
    hello(x, y)

def function_y(object):
    dostuff...
    object.bye()
    dostuff...
    function_x()
```

**main.py**

```
from xxx import some
from funtions import function_x, function_y

object = some.thing()

function_y(object)
```

Or even pack function_x and function_y in separated packages. Hard to decide without understanding the purposes.

Comment: :-) Thank you. You both are right. putting function_x into functions is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to structure your code like this:

### main.py

```
from xxx import some
import functions

object = some.thing()

functions.function_y(object)
```

### functions.py

```
from yyy import hello

def function_x():
    dostuff...
    hello(x, y)

def function_y(obj):
    dostuff...
    obj.bye() #object passed as parameter
    dostuff...
    function_x() #function now local in function.py
```